# Link click toggleClass on fixed element (off canvas menu) causes jump to top of page

Tags: jquery, html, css

So i have the following markup. I have a sticky navigation bar (menu-bar), which when the button is clicked the off-canvas menu is shown using css transitions by adding a class (slide-wrapper__open) to the html element.

**HTML**

```
    <div class="menu-bar">
    <div class="menu-btn">
        <a href="" class="menu-btn__toggle">
            <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="slide-wrapper">
    <nav class="nav-menu">
        <ul class="nav-menu__menu">

        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
@import "../modules/mixins";

.menu-bar {
  @include mobile {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    position: fixed;
    border-bottom: 1px solid $lightGreyBorder;
    background: white;
    z-index: 100;
  }
  @include tablet {
   display:none;
  }
  @include tablet-land {
    display:none;
  }
  @include desktop {
    display: none;
  }
}

.menu-btn {
  @include mobile {
    height: inherit;
    width: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    float: right;
  }
}

.slide-wrapper {
  @include mobile {
    width:80%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 0;

  }
  @include tablet {
   display:none;
  }
  @include tablet-land {
    display:none;
  }
  @include desktop {
    display: none;
  }

  .nav-menu {
    @include mobile {
      position: absolute;
      background: rgba(0,0,0,0.65);
      width: 100%;
      right: -100%;
      height: 100%;
      transition: ease 0.5s all;
    }
  }
}

.slide-wrapper__open {
  .page {
    @include mobile {
      right: 80%;
      transition: ease 0.5s all;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
  }
  .slide-wrapper {
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 0;

    .nav-menu {
      @include mobile {
        right: 0%;
        transition: ease 0.5 all;
      }
    }

  }
}

.page {
  @include mobile {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
    right: 0;
    transition: ease 0.6s all;
  }
}
```

**JS**

```
$(".class").click(function(e){ //stack overflow is giving me code errors but the class name i used was the correct one.
    e.preventDefault();
    $("html").toggleClass("slide-wrapper__open");
});
```

However when I click the link the page immediately scroll all the way to the top of the page and opens the off canvas menu. When i remove this toggle class and click the page does not scroll to the top but obviously the menu does not appear.

As a result I know that this is either an issue with CSS transitions or the toggleClass function. Ive tried everything from return false, to #! in the link, attempting to scroll back to the position that the click occurred at ($(document).scrollTop(SCROLL_POS);) etc. The scroll method only partly works when the menu is closed if open (class is added to html tag) it stills scrolls all the way to the top of the page.

Can anyone give me advise as to if there is a solution to this problem.

Thanks

**EDIT - Original**

[ORIGINAL JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2y4vabta/2/)

**EDIT - Working**

[WORKING JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2y4vabta/5/)

Comment: That `<a>` tag needs some sort of text content to be accessible. Use an `aria-label="menu"` attribute or something like Bootstrap's `sr-only` CSS class if you don't want the text to be visible.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is default browser behavior due to the `href=""`. And since the `preventDefault` isn't holy either the only good solution would be to return a void to DOM. Try this if you haven't done already:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="menu-btn__toggle">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
</a>
```

Comment: Well, i think i have found the issue, locking the screen using overflow hidden forces the page to the top if i remove that line it now works.

Comment: The solution was to remove overflow hidden on the .page class and instead apply it to .menu-bar__open which gets added to html. This stops the scroll to top behaviour when overflow hidden is applied to .page. This was purely a css issues since i had tested that events hadn't propagated prior to asking the question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can tell if your problem is caused by link by checking if clicking on your div does actually adds a hash to your url. A standalone hash is equivalent to "_top" so in cases like yours adding something to the anchor (even dummy number) does sometimes work.

However, if the hash is not being added (which would mean that defual event is indeed prevented) than I would guess on css problem, like height of the document scaling down below the height of the window (due to some relative positioning).

If you can afford manipulating the html a bit then putting a `span` tag inside an `a` and attaching a click event with `event.stopPropagation()` to it should do the trick. `stopPropagation` woud make sure your event doesn't bubble up to the `a` tag so the `a` tag default actions wouldn't get fired at all.